# Make Friendlier SSRS Report URLS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have SSRS reports setup something like so:
http://myserver/reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fChanges-By-SSN&ViewMode=Detail

Is there an easy way to change the url to something like:
http://myserver/reports/?changes-by-ssn

These reports are going to be used by non-technical people and I'd like the url to be friendlier and easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried URL Rewrite with SSRS, so don't know how easy it would be.

What about the other way? Either integrate a ReportViewer into your application so that users can select a report from a list of reports.

And/or create report models and allow to use a ReportBuilder - URLs in that case are pretty clean and users work with models and folder-like structure

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple asp.net page, that accepts the pretty url and uses Server.Redirect or Server.Transfer (if you want to keep the redirect hidden), to show the correct report. Or use a ReportViewer, that shows the correct report depending on the url parameter.

The only problme has to do with authentication. Perhaps you'll have to impersonate or pass crdentials or use any other method, because, depending on your chosen solution, it will be the web application identity the one that will acces the report server.